# PHP Sessions: Make non-PHP files require login

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, file-type

I am setting up a little page with a quite simple login-system via PHP Sessions. Business as usual: the correct Username/Password combination sets $_SESSION['login'] to *true*. When opening /page1.php or /page2.php a few lines of PHP will check the login state.
As I would like to have it nice and secure I would also like to keep unauthorized visitors from accessing files other than .php, for instance my javascript or CSS files.

I thought of a few ways to do that:

- **htaccess/htpasswd** is the most obvious option, but I am searching for something more fancy. You know, having a custom UI etc...
- **mod_rewrite** could redirect everything everything to a PHP-file like *fetch.php?url=script.js*, which could then execute my PHP before echoing the content of *script.js*. But this way I would have to mess around with MIME-types and it would bypass all other kinds of htaccess protection. Seems like a security risk to me.
- declaring a **auto_prepend_file** in my .htaccess would do a similar job, yet it does not create any MIME-type problems or security issues. I couldn't really get it to work on my server, probably deactivated by my server-host.

Do you have any additional idea? I assume this is a common problem, so there should be a solution for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create a [tag:.htaccess] rule to redirect all requests to `index.php` in which you check login. If such exists, place a header('Contenttype') and echo any file.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by wanting something more fancy, as opposed to using htaccess? Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want, with htaccess, you can simply disallow anyone from accessing css/js files directly.

Comment: I agree with @UnamataSanatarai, read all files via php file then check for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it consistent (not have one login via php and one via basic auth) you'll need to run all your assets through php.  However I highly recommend against this from several performance reasons:

1. Incurrs lot more to latency server files via PHP vs. the server daemon (nginx/apache)
2. Add unnecessary load on server CPU and memory
3. Wastes time locking up processes that could be use to serve up more requests
4. You'll never be able to use a CDN with this logged-in only requirement for

I think the main suggestion in my answer is to rethink what you're doing that requires you're client to be logged in to access CSS and JS assets.  Are you putting passwords in the JS or something?  If so, I recommend deeper evaluation of your architecture over passing all assets through PHP.